# Java: startingPath as "public static final" exception

Tags: java, static, scope, final

**[Updated, sorry about the change but now to the real problem]**
I cannot include try-catch-loop there for the exception from the method getCanonicalPath(). I tried to solve the problem earlier with method and then declaring the value there. The problem is that it is Final, I am unable to change it. So how to have startingPath as "public static final".

```
$ cat StartingPath.java 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StartingPath {
 public static final String startingPath = (new File(".")).getCanonicalPath();

 public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(startingPath);
 }
}
$ javac StartingPath.java 
StartingPath.java:5: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 public static final String startingPath = (new File(".")).getCanonicalPath();
                                                                           ^
1 error
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866770/how-to-handle-a-static-final-field-initializer-that-throws-checked-exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name is fine; you forgot to declare the type.

```
public static final String startingPath;
//                  ^^^^^^
```

---

Fixing that, you of course realize the harder problem of how to deal with the possible `IOException` and `startingPath` being `final`. One way is to use a `static` initializer:

#### [JLS 8.7 Static Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7)

> Any *static initializers* declared in a class are executed when the class is initialized and, together with any field initializers for class variables, may be used to initialize the class variables of the class.

```
 public static final String startingPath;
 static {
    String path = null;
    try {
      path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // do whatever you have to do
    }
    startingPath = path;
 }
```

Another way is to use a `static` method (see [Kevin Brock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613952/java-startingpath-as-public-static-final-exception/2613987#2613987)). That approach actually results in better readability, and is the recommended approach by Josh Bloch in *Effective Java*.

---

#### See also

- [How to handle a static final field initializer that throws checked exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866770/how-to-handle-a-static-final-field-initializer-that-throws-checked-exception)
- [In what order do static initializer blocks in Java run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run)

Comment: I don't see which parts are: initialization, declaration and assignment. It is hard to understand the term final without focusing on them separately.

Comment: I think Kevin Brock's `private static` method solution provides the most readability. I recommend using that approach. That's also what Josh Bloch recommends in _Effective Java_ (see the question I linked to); I don't think it's ethical of me to incorporate that late into my answer after his (unless he gives me permission to).

Answer (score 5):

You can provide a static method to initialize your static variable:

```
public static final String startingPath = initPath();

private static String initPath() {
    try {
        return new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Got I/O exception during initialization", e);
    }
}
```

Or you can initialize your variable in a static block:

```
public static final String startingPath;

static {
    try {
        startingPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Got I/O exception during initialization", e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: In this case your variable is `static` so there is no way to declare the exception thrown. Just for reference, if the variable is non-`static` you could do this by declaring the thrown exception in the constructor, like so:

```
public class PathHandler {

    private final String thePath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();

    public PathHandler() throws IOException {
        // other initialization
    }
```

Comment: I'm usually throwing ExceptionInInitializerError.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize it in the static block(the variable is final). You can't catch exceptions on declaring a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type of your variable, it should be

```
public static void String startingPath ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static final String startingPath = (new File(".")).getCanonicalPath();
```

You are missing the type of variable  `startingPath`