# The final field may not/already have been initialized

Tags: java, initialization, field, final

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle a static final field initializer that throws checked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866770/how-to-handle-a-static-final-field-initializer-that-throws-checked-exception)

In this example, I get the error *The blank final field myClass may **not** have been initialized*:

```java
private final static MyClass myClass; // <-- error

static {
    try {
        myClass = new MyClass(); // <-- throws exception
        myClass.init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log
    }
}
```

In that example, I get the error *The final field myClass may **already** have been assigned*:

```java
private final static MyClass myClass;

static {
    try {
        myClass = new MyClass(); // <-- throws exception
        myClass.init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myClass = null; // <-- error
        // log
    }
}
```

In there any solution to that issue?

Comment: Can your `MyClass` constructor throw an exception? Or is it `init()` method that can throw exception?

Comment: i think it's the initialize method that can throw, right? Because in that case, myClass can have an assigned value in the catch block.

Comment: Let's says the constructor can throw an exception too. In fact, it's an example that illustrates the issue I ran into with another piece of code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
private final static MyClass myClass;

static {
    MyClass my;
    try {
        my = new MyClass();
        my.init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        my = null;
        // log
    }
    myClass = my; //only one assignment!
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution :

```
private final static MyClass myClass = buildInstance();

private static MyClass buildInstance() {
    try {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.init();
        return myClass;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That suits perfectly my needs, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your class is final it can't change values once it is initialised.
What you are doing in the second snippet is that you are first assigning it to `new MyClass()` and then if an Exception is thrown in `init()` you then change it to `null`.

This is not allowed. If `new MyClass()` does not throw an Exception why don't you put it at the top line?

Warning though, that if `init()` throws an Exception, you will still have an unintialised instance of `MyClass`. It doesn't seem that the way you're working with this class matches the way its designed to work.